# Date difference in days Restriction Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am using Hibernate and Criteria API to write my database quires. What I need to do is I need two dates difference in days and compare that days with with specific number.

E.g. Commonly written criteria restriction as:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("somProperty", someValue));
```

What I needs is:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("dateProperty1 - dateProperty2", 15));
```

Means date difference between two dates is greater than or equal 15 days.

I don't see how to achieve this. And yes I did lots of Google to find out the possible solution but didn't get proper material what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the documentation of the [Restrictions](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html) class, you will see that:

- most functions operate on a "property vs value" pair (just like in your first example)
- the remaining comparator functions operate on "property vs other property" pair

**But no customized function is available for your case.** So what option you have is using the `sqlRestriction`, which can be used to express this condition in a native form of your DBMS. That would be a different, but much easier problem, altough clearly not as elegant as your original idea.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replay..I am checking sqlRestriction() in that we need to give alias of table but how I come to know what alias given by the Hibernate to the table I intended to query..

Comment: Uhhh, that javadoc is confusing as hell. But no, you do not have to know the alias. What it meant to say, is that you can reference your table like this: `{alias}.dateProperty`, and Hibernate will substitute the real alias for you.

Comment: Yes I got your point but when we write {alias}.property hibernate will substitute the alias of table on which we are created the criteria. e.g..session.createCriteria(MyPojo.class); so {alias} get substitute with the alias for MyPojo.

Comment: And what would you like instead of this behavior?

Comment: But in my case I am writing join query using criteria and in that join I need to write query for different table apart from the original one for which criteria was created. eg. session.createCriteria(MyPojo.class,"myPojo");
criteria.createAlias("myPojo.anatherPojo", "anatherPojo"); and for this anatherPojo I need to write sqlRestriction

Comment: the problem is how can I get the alias for anatherPojo created by hibernate.. hope you got my point..

Comment: I see. The fact that your two properties are from different tables was missing from the original question. That is bad news, there are only workarounds for this problem. See this: http://www.unidev.com/web-development-insights/article/3418/Restrictions-on-table-alias-in-Hibernate-Criteria-sqlRestriction.aspx

Comment: hey thanks for your time.. this is exactly what I did few minutes before.. ;)